# Back ticks not showing up?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

The back-tick "result-of-quote" character ` used in *nix scripts doesn't appear to render properly in posts.

```
a=` cat file.txt`
```

Mmh it is working here but it definitely not working on the following post :

[Pi not reading file using Bash script on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27837/22454)

Answer (score 5):

Backticks are used for the [Markdown syntax for inline code](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).  Thus, if you write:

```
Use `cat ` instead of `<`
```

it renders as:

> Use `cat` instead of `<`

With "cat" and "<" in a monospace font (and with a gray background, but you can't see that inside a blockquote, since those have the exact same gray background color).

---

To get a literal backtick in normal text, you can simply escape it with a backslash, like this: `` "\`" `` → "`".

Getting a literal backtick into an inline code span is a bit tricky, but there's a (somewhat poorly documented) way to do it, by using *multiple backticks* as alternative code delimiters.  That is, if you want to write:

> Use `` `cat ` `` instead of `` `<` ``

you can do so by typing:

```
 Use `` `cat ` `` instead of `` `<` ``
```

Another way to achieve the same result is to use HTML `<code>` tags, like this:

```
 Use <code>\`cat \`</code> instead of <code>\`<\`</code>
```

or like this:

```
 Use <code>&#96;cat &#96;</code> instead of <code>&#96;<&#96;</code>
```

(where `&#96;` is the HTML character entity for a backtick).  Both of these render the same way as the previous example above.

Ps. The (multi)backtick syntax also works in comments, but `<code>` tags (or HTML tags in general) don't.

Answer (score 3):

It renders correctly if you put the code on a separate line and the wrap it as Preformatted  Text (code). Like this:

```
`cat `
```